# what does the expression "fetching URLs" actually mean?

Tags: python, request, urllib

I am learning to use `urllib` Python module.

When we use it, sometimes we code like:

```
req = urllib.request.Request(URL)
 urlopen(req)
```

or directly use urlopen from the start like:

```
urllib.request.urlopen
```

But as I tried to understand the logical flow of how to code, 
I got confused about the term itself: why does the term fetching URL was named to describe that behavior?

In my novice level understanding of it, to fetch URL means to retrieve "URLs" but when we use the function like `urlopen()` which is to fetch URLs, we are the ones who give URLs to the function and the function doesn't fetch URLs but give us the response object, is it correct too?

Or it only means "fetching (data with the given) URLs?

Does "to request" mean something else?

What logical element am I missing in my explanation?

Comment: @QHarr That one is totally unrelated and is a Javascript only (for now) API.

Comment: Sth. very similar was already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38816032/what-does-urllib-request-urlopen-do?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mostly already answered yourself with

> Or it only means "fetching (data with the given) URLs?

As the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/urllib2.html#fetching-urls) states:

> HTTP is based on requests and responses - the client makes requests and servers send responses. urllib.request mirrors this with a Request object which represents the HTTP request you are making. In its simplest form you create a Request object that specifies the URL you want to fetch. Calling urlopen with this Request object returns a response object for the URL requested. This response is a file-like object, which means you can for example call .read() on the response […]

Further,  the method `urlopen` accepts either a string or a `Request` object (see [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#module-urllib.request)):

> The urllib.request module defines the following functions:
>
> `urllib.request.urlopen`(url, data=None, [timeout, ]*, cafile=None,
>   capath=None, cadefault=False, context=None)
>
> Open the URL url, which can be either a string or a Request object.

Comment: So as I understood it, "requesting" is the start of fetching URLs(like initialization of requesting action) and urlopen covers the action of processing response from a server? Maybe I can summarize this sequence of logic as in [requesting->dealing with response(urlopen()) ]Thank you for your answer!

Comment: You either create a [Request](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.Request) object with the given URL or pass the URL directly as string to `urlopen`. For more information please refer to the linked documentation as it would blow out of proportion of this question. If I answered your question, please don't forget to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: so the object of fetching action(= what it actually fetches) is not URL itself but some resource right? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it bears some relation to purpose,  `fetching` something from the url e.g. example usage as described for the [API fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) from javascript.

> The Fetch API provides an interface for fetching resources (including
>   across the network). It will seem familiar to anyone who has used
>   XMLHttpRequest, but the new API provides a more powerful and flexible
>   feature set.
>
> The fetch() method takes one mandatory argument, the path to the
>   resource you want to fetch. It returns a Promise that resolves to the
>   Response to that request, whether it is successful or not. You can
>   also optionally pass in an init options object as the second argument
>   (see Request).

It is because you are fetching something from the url.